# SQLite is not storing int properly, storing it as b'\x06\x00\x00\x00'

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to insert integer in SQL table with datatype of column as INTEGER.

`df_asgn['Attempts'] = df_asgn['Attempts'].apply(lambda x: randint(0,6)).astype('int32')`

But still in database it is geeting stored as : [snip of SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Liz.png)

And on retreiving the value from table using fetchone() the output I'm getting is :
`b'\x06\x00\x00\x00'` instead of just `6`

I want to keep the data as integer only. Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "I want to keep the data as integer only" Then the SQL table must have been created with that type for that column in the first place.

Comment: Yes, it is already an INTEGER column .
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Assignments
        (assignment Text, student_id TEXT, teacher_id TEXT, due_date TEXT, status TEXT, attempts INTEGER, best_score FLOAT);`